# Mediainfo wrapper for Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jna, mediainfo

i'm pretty new to coding, especially using external library in intellij. I'm trying to load mediainfo to intellij to extract metadata of video files. I downloaded jna.jar and mediainfo.jar and placed them under my lib directory. I set them as my library and added as dependencies but I keep getting errors that says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mediainfo': Native library (darwin/libmediainfo.dylib) not found in resource path" 
I would really appreciate a detailed explanation on where to place what files in order to use mediainfo in java. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably there is a mismatch between JVM and native library CPU architectures (i.e. you must have 64-bit JVM with 64-bit native libraries, or 32-bit JVM with 32-bit native libraries).